# String is in array returning strange results

Tags: python

I'm creating a dynamic array of UUIDs, and I have another list of existing UUIDs, I want to delete items from the existing list that aren't in the new dynamic list. I'm trying to do this like this

```
# Remove components that aren't being updated
new_component_id_for_existing_sections = []
for component in new_components:
    if component.get('section_holder_id'):
        new_component_id_for_existing_sections.append(component.get('component_id'))

    print('New component IDs')
    for com in new_component_id_for_existing_sections:
        print(com)

    print('Checking existing components')
    for existing_component in self.get_object().components.all():
        print(existing_component.component.id)
        print(existing_component.component.id not in new_component_id_for_existing_sections)
```

So in here I create the array `new_component_id_for_existing_sections` which in my example has two IDs in, and `self.get_object().components.all()` has 3 ids in. But the output for this gives me.

```
New component IDs
acae9374-d32d-4752-ba5a-9437a54dbbe7
a2a9d893-86ba-4d1d-938e-f638e7b2a4b2

Checking existing components
f3cb3cc6-4d66-4df5-8232-2c1f858c8632 <----Not in the array but returns that it is
True 

acae9374-d32d-4752-ba5a-9437a54dbbe7
True

a2a9d893-86ba-4d1d-938e-f638e7b2a4b2
True
```

The first item is saying it's in the array, but it isn't and I can't figure out why

Comment: Why not use `set` and take difference?

Comment: I'm quite a novice when it comes to Python, do you mean create two sets and compare them?

Comment: That says that none of those are in `new_component_id_for_existing_sections`. From the looks of it, the first one should print `True`, and the other two `False` – not the other way around.

Comment: Ah yeah, either way though something strange is happening and I can't figure out what's up with it. Does python do anything special when comparing strings?

Comment: Where you have declared new_components ??

Comment: @SumitYadav I've solved the question, but new_components came from a request.data instance

Comment: Oh @DanielSims I got it! I am sorry it was my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a type issue, existing_component.component.id is a UUID, and the array items are strings, and it didn't like comparing UUID -> Strings.

Adding this solved the issue `existing_component.component.id.__str__()`